# The only way to get php-pdo working with mysql 5.6 breaks mysql 5.6

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, drupal-7

I am running something in drupal 7 and have come across the issue with how Mysql 5.1 does not completely implement utf-8 characters. The recommended solution is to install mysql5.6.

Here is my current system configuration:

```
Ubuntu server 10.04
Apache 2 
Php 5
Drupal 7
Mysql 5.6
```

After a day of struggling to get mysql 5.6 installed, I found this tutorial which got it working: http://www.howtoforge.com/how-to-install-mysql-5.6-on-ubuntu-12.10-including-memcached-plugin

Now when I go to install drupal, it states

```
Database support    Disabled
Your web server does not appear to support any common PDO database extensions.
```

I installed php-pdo and enabled it in the config, but drupal cannot see it and phpinfo() gives the following for the pdo section:

```
    PDO
PDO support enabled
PDO drivers     no value
```

After a few hours on Google, I found that the solution is to do the following:

```
 apt-get install --reinstall php5-gd php5-mysql
```

except that reinstalling php-mysql somehow breaks mysql 5.6 and makes it not start. I'm not exactly sure why and I have exhausted every result on Google for this problem, so now I turn to you. Does anyone have experience with this? I've never had any trouble with mysql 5.1.

I appreciate any insight anyone has into this issue.

Comment: Error messages would be of some help.

Comment: There are no errors prior to reinstalling php-mysql. It simply just does not load the module. After reinstalling php-mysql, trying to start mysql 5.6 gives this:


`user@hostV:~$ sudo service mysql.server  start`
`Starting MySQL`
` * Couldn't find MySQL server (/usr/bin/mysqld_safe)`